# How to remove String inside string? C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a variable with values similar to:

```
  A-something_123.png
  B-othersomething_43.png
```

I want to remove the strings between chars "_" and "."

I want to keep:

```
A-something.png
B-othersomething.png
```

Could you please give me a hand?

Comment: What have you tried so far for replacing the string?

Comment: im searching an example with remove() and charIndex() i guess

Comment: maybe read about regular expressions to find the desired part of the string (between `_` and `.`).
Then a method `public static string Replace (string input, string pattern, string replacement);` in `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` could help you.
There is also a nice tool to test your regular expressions https://regex101.com/

Comment: `var s = "something_123.png"; var s2 = string.Concat(s.Split('_').First(), Path.GetExtension(s));`

Answer (score 3):

Regex can be used:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"_[^_\.]+\.", ".");
```

It is actually quite optimal for large data sets.